# Getting Exception in Converting ByteArray to String with Fixed length

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to convert bytes in to String.

I have one android application and I am using `flatfile` for data storage.

Suppose I have lots of record in my `flatfile`.

Here in flat file database, my record size is fixed and its `10` characters and here I am storing lots of String records sequence.

But when I read one record from the flat file, then it is fixed number of bytes for each record. Because I wrote 10 bytes for every record.

If my string is `S="abc123";`
then it is stored in flat file like `abc123 ASCII values for each character and rest would be 0`.
Means byte array should be `[97 ,98 ,99 ,49 ,50 ,51,0,0,0,0]`.
So when I want to get my actual string from the byte array, at that time I am using below code and it is working fine.

But when I give my `inputString = "1234567890"` then it creates problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static short messageNumb = 0;
    public static short appID = 16;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // record with size 10 and its in bytes.
        byte[] recordBytes = new byte[10];
        // fill record by 0's
        Arrays.fill(recordBytes, (byte) 0);

        // input string
        String inputString = "abc123";
        int length = 0;
        int SECTOR_LENGTH = 10;
        // convert in bytes
        byte[] inputBytes = inputString.getBytes();
        // set how many bytes we have to write.
        length = SECTOR_LENGTH < inputBytes.length ? SECTOR_LENGTH
                : inputBytes.length;

        // copy bytes in record size.
        System.arraycopy(inputBytes, 0, recordBytes, 0, length);

        // Here i write this record in the file.
        // Now time to read record from the file.
        // Suppose i read one record from the file successfully.

        // convert this read bytes to string which we wrote.
        Log.d("TAG", "String is  = " + getStringFromBytes(recordBytes));

    }

    public String getStringFromBytes(byte[] inputBytes) {
        String s;
        s = new String(inputBytes);
        return s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(0));
    }
}
```

But I am getting problem when my string has complete 10 characters. At that time I have two 0's in my byte array so in this line
`s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(0));`

I am getting the below exception:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
```

So what can I do when my string length is 10.

I have two solutions- I can check my `inputBytes.length == 10` then make it not to do subString condition otherwise `check contains 0 in byte array`.

But i don't want to use this solution because I used this thing at lots of places in my application. So, is there any other way to achieve this thing?

Please suggest me some good solution which works in every condition. I think at last 2nd solution would be great. (check contains 0's in byte array and then apply sub string function).

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier and also faster to use SQLite as your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String getStringFromBytes(byte[] inputBytes) {
    String s;
    s = new String(inputBytes);
    int zeroIndex = s.indexOf(0);
    return zeroIndex < 0 ? s : s.substring(0, zeroIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this line cause the error

```
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(0));

s.indexOf(0)
```

returns -1 , perhaps you should specifiy the ASCII code 
for zero which is `48`

so this will work   `s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(48));`

check documentation for indexOf(int)

> public int indexOf (int c) Since: API Level 1 Searches in this string
>   for the first index of the specified character. The search for the
>   character starts at the beginning and moves towards the end of this
>   string.
>
> Parameters c  the character to find. Returns the index in this string
>   of the specified character, -1 if the character isn't found.

Comment: Here `indexOf(0)` and `indexOf(48)` is different thing. so `indexOf(48)` will not work